# How do I set a maneuver point on the surface?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

In the [Luna 9 tutorial](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Tutorial:_Luna_9#Braking_maneuver) on the KSP wiki, it says:

> To keep track of how much time you have left, set a maneuver point on the surface.

How do I go about setting a maneuver point on the surface? I can't set the Mun as a target, so presumably that's not what it's talking about.

Comment: Interesting.  I don't think I've ever set a maneuver point on the surface.  I think the idea is that you're supposed to being "landing", and then set a maneuver node at the point where your orbit intersects Mun.

Comment: I know of no way to make sure a maneuver point is placed precisely on the surface.  For the purposes of gauging distance and time, though, it should be fine to put a point down as close as your mouse lets you before the trajectory disappears.

Comment: There is no way to do that, just put a node close to the surface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wiki page is talking about a maneuver node that you would normally use in space to mark a prograde/retrograde/etc. burn. There is no special "landing" node. By placing it on or near the surface, you can gauge roughly how much time you have until landing.

There is currently no stock way to place one exactly on the surface. Just place one as close to the surface as the game will allow.

You don't really need to worry about the inaccuracy of not being able to click on the exact landing point of your trajectory, because unless you're at the very margin of your fuel supply, it doesn't hurt to have the extra few seconds of buffer before the last few meters of your visual approach.

Once you are within the last few meters of your landing, you should be able to judge your height based on your shadow, which should now be visible.

If you *are* running very low on fuel, you should quicksave and then try suicide burns from different altitudes and not worry about your time to impact as such.

Comment: The wiki appears to be talking about this in relation to timing the visual approach. That is: until you've done a few landings, it's difficult to judge altitude, etc. visually.

Comment: I meant the visual approach as the last few dozen meters.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe, I updated the wording. Is this more satisfactory?

Comment: Yes. I've expanded on your answer and (possibly) explained the source of my confusion.

Comment: Good edit, that really improves the answer!